# the volume is already mounted warning when using TrueCrypt through command prompt

Tags: cmd, truecrypt

So I have created a batch file which takes in the following command:

truecrypt /a favorites /v PATH TO my TRUECRYPT VOLUME /p PASSWORD /q

When I run this command i get a pop up saying "The volume is already mounted". I tried restarting the system and still it gives me the same warning.

Could you let me know why we get this error? Because this warning is showing up,the other commands in the batch file are not getting executed.The execution continues only when I click ok on the warning.

So I also wanted to know if I could send commands from my command prompt to this window to click on "ok" which would help in the execution of the next commands in the batch file. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when we use /q in the command then we have to use /s or /silent which suppresses all the warnings.

Comment: Your answer solved my unsolved truecrypt mount and unmount errors. Very thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

you should also use /f to force dismount to avoid any open processes blocking the unmount command.